# How do I define pagination parameters in my schema?

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to create the ability to paginate through my data, but I'm not sure where I need to place the pagination variables.

**Here is what I have in my schema:**

```
const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  description: 'This is a root Query',
  fields: () => {
    return {
      allPosts: {
        type: new GraphQLList(Post),
        args: {
          offset: {
            type: GraphQLInt
          },
          first: {
            type: GraphQLInt
          }
        },
        resolve(root, args) {
          return Db.models.post.findAll({where: args});
        }
      }
    };
  }
});
```

In my args, I've created the variables *offset* and *first* to be able to use them. Inside in my **graphiQL** interface I can do this:

```
{
    allPosts() {
    id
    }
}
```

And it correctly retrieves all my posts. However if I try to do this:

```
{
    allPosts(offset:10, first: 10) {
    id
    }
}
```

**"message": "Unknown column 'post.offset' in 'where clause'",**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sequelize, `offset` is a separate option from `where`. Sequelize also doesn't have a `first` option, but it does have a `limit`. You can do something like:

```
resolve(root, { offset, first: limit }) {
  return Db.models.post.findAll({offset, limit});
}
```

You can check out the docs [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) to see all the options supported by `findAll`.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I was looking in the wrong place! I should have been looking at the Sequelize docs! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would be very careful about passing args directly into your DB, but as a point of clarity, I should say that GraphQL does not do pagination for you. You can pass in args like you are doing but there is no right answer here about where to put them or how to use them since everybody gets data in their way.

Comment: Hm what do you mean be careful? How else am I supposed to paginate and do search queries? Is there a safer way?